# How to manage catalog inventory/product quantity in website level in Magento 2 (admin )

Tags: product, magento2

I created a multi store website in magento 2,but I want to manage each product on the website level.

For example, I have one product sku is sku200, and my websites are "India" and "England" I want make product qty for India "1000" and for England "500",means I want to handle each and every product separately for India and England at website level.

Comment: @tecjam i am asking website level not store level..

Comment: So instead of selecting Store View as scope, select Website. I've added an extra screenshot to the answer below.

Comment: @tecjam , we can select website but the problem is when we enter price for the particular product ,that price is saving global not website level,  see the question properly (inventory management at website level)  .

Comment: Why Price? You are asking about Inventory, not price. Maybe re-read your own question?

Comment: @ tecjam ,in inventory  we have price and quantity right?

Comment: let me clarify ,,,we have 2 website (A and B)  again A have stores (xx and yy)  and B have stores(zz and qq) , lets take product sku10 , i want product sku10 in website A( price=100 and quantity=100) for website B( price=200 and quantity=200) .   now you are clear.

Comment: @AnandOntigeri how did you handle this?

Answer (score 3):

Once you've created the product and saved it, the scope selector will appear which lets you select which `Website/Store` view to edit the product for.

The Problem you will have is that the Quanity field is set to [**GLOBAL**], which means it will use the value globally and it can not be edited for each website or store view.

You would have to change that first in `Stores > Attributes > Product > Attribute` **Code**: `quantity_and_stock_status` and edit the scope to Store View or in your case Website. See the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: we can set Quanity field "website"

Comment: stores->Attribute->product-> and search for "quantity_and_stock_status"

Comment: Properties->Advanced Attribute Properties->Scope   we can change scope

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I've edited my answer.

Comment: This will not work, because the attribute "quantity_and_stock_status" is not the actual quantity attribute. If you open this attribute you can see, its input type is "drop down" and it takes values as "In stock"  and "out of stock". Its not saving the quantity of the product.

Comment: its not working , how i can change it plz to website scope or storeview